# Excel use sum function and delete suming number

Tags: excel

i have a excel file
and B1 = A1+A1
this is an example

```
10|20
20|40
30|60
```

the problem is i'm trying to delete th A column and save data for B column,

but when i'm trying to delete it , the B column is returning  0 to all B value

is there a way to save B value and delete A value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after copying the data right click then do paste values